# Почему в форме не отображается строка с email?

Tags: python, django, email

Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию по почте, все делал по этому гайду

https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef

но в форме строчка с email не отображается, хотя я указал это в **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**signup.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
      {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**myblog/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm


from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'post_comment.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    #fields = '__all__'

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

Если понадобится, скажите какие еще файлы показать, все покажу конечно же

п.с. небольшая ремарочка, в форме у меня указаны 4 строки: 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', именно 'email' почему то не отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок в django, буду благодарен абсолютно любому совету,
Спасибо!

Comment: У вас не отображается само поле и атрибут help_text у поля email?

Comment: из 4ех филдов именно email не отоброжается

Comment: Простите, но я не могу ответить на ваш вопрос. Я скопировал класс вашей формы и ваш шаблон, но у меня поле email нормально отображалось. Попробуйте убрать логику из вашей view(signup) и просто передать форму в шаблон т.е form = SignupForm() и всё. Напишите отобразилось ли поле emial при простом отображении формы.

Comment: form в таком случае принимает серый цвет и становится как неиспользуемая

Comment: Миша, можно ваш телеграмм? или напишите мне пожалуйста @Pppperfect,

Мне с оф стека написали вот такой текст 

*I bet you didn't notice your SignUpView class in your views.py uses UserCreationForm as its form_class, not SignupForm*

как я могу импортировать "SignupForm" из **myblog/forms.py** в **views.py** чтобы его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не отображается атрибут help_text у поля email, то тут несколько решений.

1. Просто в шаблоне вывести (без цикла) `{{form.as_p}}`, соответственно будет выведена форма с именами полей и так же будет выведен help_text.
2. В цикле `{% for field in form %}` обратиться к `{{field.help_text}}`
3. В файле forms.py, в вашей форме SignupForm, у поля email сделать widget. То есть:

`email=forms.EmialField(max_length=200, widget=(forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Это поле является обязательным'})))'`

И в attrs можно указать placeholder.

Comment: я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, не хочу дезинформировать

Answer (score 0):

в **accounts/views.py** в form_class был UserCreationForm, вместо SignupForm